# Firefox /Debian /ARM64?

Tags: firefox, debian, arm

Does anyone know how to install current Firefox on Debian Stretch on ARM64? Not Iceweasel or Firefox ESR. It is not in the standard repository and Firefox does not display any download links.

Comment: I believe the source code is available. Have you tried anything with it?

Comment: @kamil-maciorowski I was hoping that there would be a compiled build around.

Answer (score 0):

As of this date, Firefox's latest ARM builds are only available through the sid repositories on Debian.  Today, you can install Firefox 108 as follows:

**Warning: This may cause problems with your system:**

```bash
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ sid main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && apt-get update -qqy \
  && apt-get -qqy install firefox libavcodec-extra
```

However, it's not generally advisable to add sid sources to a non-sid version.  So first, you'd only do this at your own risk, and second, you'd probably want to remove the "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ sid main" entry from /etc/apt/sources.list after installing so that you don't corrupt your system by installing other packages from sid, assuming this won't corrupt it already.

I follow the *above* approach for a [Firefox/Selenium ARM64 Docker container image](https://github.com/seleniumhq-community/docker-seleniarm/blob/trunk/NodeFirefox/Dockerfile.multi-arch). Since the containers are short-lived and don't require ongoing updates at runtime, there's no major issues with this approach. However, if you're trying to install the latest on a non-sid installed production system, then I'd personally advise against it. So please use the above approach at your own risk. :)

**Safer, more conservative approach:**

Although it's not what you want -- you specified *current* arm64 version -- a safer bet would be to install Firefox 102 (at the time of this writing) from the firefox-esr package. It's not as up to date with the latest Firefox, but it's less likely to create problems with your system.

For those who want the firefox-esr package, here is how to install it on Debian Bullseye:

```
$ sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get install firefox-esr
```